# How to add padding to all cells of a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to add padding (not margins) to each cell in a recycler view. The elements of this recycler view are used throughout my app, so I don't want to add the padding directly to the XML.

I understand that we can use decorators to add margins to the children of the recycler view, but what is the best way to add padding? The issue I have with the decorator is that the background color of the cells does not extend to the edges of the recycler view when I use it.

Is there a way to do this, or should I duplicate the XML for each cell type to add padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searching in google and Android documentation, I found this [link](https://gist.github.com/vincetreur/4623110107c07c44b390) go to the link, which margin the items of recycler view using `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` but not padding. instead remove mPadding value or assign = 0 then add this code `view.setPadding(5,5,5,5);`

```
@Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        view.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // add left, top, right, bottom 5px
        final int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (itemPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return;
        }
```

then call the class in mainActivity

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(ListPaddingDecoration(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand that you don't want to add padding to the main XML file, because to achive this you could just add padding to the item XML.

When you add the padding to the XML file related to the item, all item have it.

so if we have to XML, one for main activity in which we show all class of a school there will be a class_item.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Class name"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I don't want to add padding to the XML because those items are reused throughout my app and should only have the padding when in this particular recycler view

Comment: Sorry, i suppose you didn't want add padding to the recycler view widget

Comment: I personally would do it by creating a two different XML, i don't get what could trouble in have two XML.

Other solution would be constantlty change the padding when the cells are visible, i don't think is good for performance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want to set padding in code (programmatically). You can do it by using method on your root View of recycler item: setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

Comment: The problem of doing that is you have to do it to all cell of recycler view, adding padding to recycler view itself will not add padding between each cells

Comment: That is true, you would have to do that in viewholder of the item. Another option is creating two XMLs.

Comment: You can also try to look for a suitable method using recyclerView.layoutManager
There are some helpful functions.